# How to dynamically change the content of a table column

Tags: javascript, html, wpf, angularjs

Given the following HTML fragment, how can I create the content of the `td` depending on the `column`.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="controller" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns">
                {{ column.header }}
            </th>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
                <!-- TODO -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Each column can show a different kinds of data. For example, one might just show a string, another might contain a text input field that is bound to a property of the row.

I would like to call a function on the column (`column.createCell(row)`) that creates that necessary HTML and then put the result in place of `<!-- TODO -->`.

In WPF, I would just put a `ContentPresenter` with a `DataTemplateSelector`, but I don't know what the equivalent is in Angular. I read about something called "ng-bind-html", is that the way to go?

Comment: You'll want to use a directive for this, passing in the column and generating the HTML for each column that way.

Comment: @wbeange: what is a directive and how do I connect it to the `td`? Could you write this as an answer please?

Comment: one sec, there you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not given what kind of custom element you want to build for each column, but for DOM manipulation in AngularJS best practise is to keep it in a directive. Something like this:

in your html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="column in row">
            <custom-column="column"></custom-column>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // whatever you wanted to define here...
  $scope.rows = ...
  $scope.columns = ...
});

app.directive('customColumn', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      obj: '=customColumn',
    },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var watcher = scope.$watch('obj', function(obj) {
        if (!obj) return;

        // build custom element
        var html = '<div>'+scope.obj.name+'</div>';
        element.html(html);

        // delete watch if you only need to draw once
        watcher();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it really `<custom-column="column">`? That seems to be invalid HTML.

Comment: A directive is a custom element in Angular. You'll want to do some reading up on that.

Comment: Older versions of IE may not like element directives, you could always write it as an attribute: <div custom-column="column"></div>

Comment: Where does `app` come from? Is that a global variable defined by angular?

Comment: app is your Angular app, I just changed the code so it'll be more clear for you. This should answer your question regarding how to dynamically change / build your DOM for each column.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer. As a bonus, if you want, how does `app` relate to the `ng-app` attribute?

Comment: in this case in the Plunker (plnkr.co) AngularJS scaffolded base app, ng-app would wrap the outside element as <html ng-app="plunker">, which is defined in the app.js script as var app = angular.module('plunker', []);